# Excel moving data from one sheet to another and placing in next empty row

Tags: vba, excel, transpose

I have values coming from a table that i am trying to write a VBA macro for to move to another sheet where it will be place in the next empty row,

here is what i have so far as far as selecting the data goes:

```
'storing the values to be moved
Dim DayID As String
Dim Shift As Integer
Dim Operator As String
Dim Operation As String
Dim PartNum As String
Dim Asset As String

'placing selected cells
Sheets("Raw Data").Select

   Range("A10000").Select
   Selection.End(xlUp).Select
   ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).select

   ActiveCell.Value = DayID
```

I got to this point to see if what i had worked with just putting the date in ad it did not. I am new to VBA and don't fully understand what i am doing yet so any help is appreciated!

the columns I'm placing the data in are in columns A, M, O, Q, N, and P respectively if that helps

Comment: Didn't you ask this yesterday? Did you delete the question?

Comment: i asked a much broader question earlier with more parts that i  had no idea how to do it and was told no one would answer it because i hadnt put what i tried first. so i narrowed the question to a small part of the original and put the code that i unsuccessfully tried in the hopes of getting an answer this time

Comment: Ah that's why it looked familiar. Well, instead of asking this question, just google it. It will take you 5 min to figure out.

Comment: I tried that for a few hours and got as far as I am now. that's why I posted on this forum... In the hopes of getting help. This is the first VBA code Ive ever written so I have little to no understanding of its applications

Comment: There's no tactful way to put this but if you **really** tried for a few hours and still can't place a value in the next empty row, please consider hiring someone. This is a question that's been asked countless times and it's not complex.

Comment: I am an intern with the sole task of creating this working excel form so I really dont have much hiring power

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes that you are working on the same workbook that contains the code. If not, you can change "ThisWorkbook" to "ActiveWorkbook". I included the `With wsTarget` even though it is currently excessive, with the belief that as you build this subroutine up, it will become increasingly relevant. Edited to place the first three variables into their appropriate columns. I leave it to you to fill in the remaining code:

```
Sub FirstStep()

'storing the values to be moved
Dim DayID As String
Dim Shift As Integer
Dim Operator As String
Dim Operation As String
Dim PartNum As String
Dim Asset As String

Dim wsTarget As Worksheet

Set wsTarget = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data") 'Would be much better to change the CodeName of the sheet and reference directly.

'placing selected cells
With wsTarget
    .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = DayID
    .Cells(Rows.Count, 13).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Shift
    .Cells(Rows.Count, 15).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Operator
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: the columns were in order of which variable it goes with

Answer (score 1):

Without fully knowing what values you want to fill in, what sheet you are starting with and how exactly you want the results to look, something like the following should at least get you started.

```
Sub test()

Dim rData As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long
Dim arr(5) As Variant

Set rData = Sheets("Raw Data")
arr(0) = "A"
arr(1) = "M"
arr(2) = "O"
arr(3) = "Q"
arr(4) = "N"
arr(5) = "P"

With rData

    For Each element In arr

        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, element).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Cells(lRow, element).Value = "Value in Column " & element

    Next element

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You misunderstood the question. The letters are columns, not elements of an array.

Comment: find window is correct, the letters are the column names

Comment: You both didn't read my code very well.  I added the column letters to the array because based on what I can tell in the question values need to be entered into specific columns, and those column may or may not have different Next rows.  This obviously isn't ideal code, but it's a good start based on the vague question

Comment: lol my fault. That's what I get for not reading the entire thing. Edit: @SamQL `lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, element).End(xlUp).Row + 1` that's the line you want to study.

Comment: :) yep, that's definitely the line to focus on.  The other stuff is just filler that needs to be replaced to cater the needs of your issue